# AngularJS Динамический ng-pattern с переменными

Tags: angularjs, шаблоны-проектирования

С помощью директивы ng-repeat вывожу список инпутов. Как 'повесить' на каждый инпут функцию которая принимает два параметра, и в зависимости от них возвращает нужный паттерн с которым бы работала директива ng-pattern? К сожалению функцию назначить `ng-pattern` не получается.

```
<div ng-repeat="arg in args track by $index">
  <input type="text" ng-pattern="customPattern" ng-model="arg.value" required>
  <!-- ng-pattern="customPattern(arg.type,arg.size)" -->
</div>
```

И JS

```
   $scope.args = [
       {is_array: 0, type:0, size:2, value:[]},
       {is_array: 0, type:1, size:3, value:[]},
       {is_array: 0, type:2, size:4, value:[]},
       {is_array: 0, type:3, size:2, value:[]},
       {is_array: 1, type:0, size:1, value:[]},
       {is_array: 1, type:1, size:1, value:[]},
       {is_array: 1, type:2, size:1, value:[]},
       {is_array: 1, type:3, size:1, value:[]},
     ];

    // $scope.customPattern(type, size){
    //   if(size==1){
    //     if(type==0) return pattern1;
    //     if(type==1) return pattern2;
    //     if(type==2) return pattern3;
    //     if(type==3) return pattern4;
    //   }
    //   else{
    //     if(type==0) return pattern5;
    //     if(type==1) return pattern6;
    //     if(type==2) return pattern7;
    //     if(type==3) return pattern8;
    //   }
    // }
```

Подправил код:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern=customPattern(arg.type,arg.size) ng-model="arg.value" required>
```

JS упрощенное условие: если size=1 в ng-pattern должно возвращаться регулярное выражение - целое число, если size>1 регулярное выражение - целые числа через запятую, количество чисел = size

```
 $scope.customPattern = function(type, size){
          if(size==1){
            var pattern=new RegExp("^\\d+$");
            return pattern;
          }else{
            var pattern=new RegExp("^(\\d+,){" + size-1 + "}\\d+$");
            return pattern;
          }
        }
```

[Пример2](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview)

Comment: закомментированный вариант вполне рабочий

Comment: но так как функции не рекомендуется использовать во view лучше всего добавить поле pattern сразу в объекты массива и просто подставлять его

Comment: Где я тогда допускаю ошибку в этом примере? http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview  первый паттерн это число с плавающей точкой, второй - целое число

Comment: отредактируй вопрос с новым условием

Comment: на самом деле проблема с регулярками

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемы с регулярками:

Так как используется функция во view, то она вызывается несколько раз во время исполнения digest цикла, а так как каждый раз при этом она возвращает **новый** объект - то после проверки, что объект digest цикл запускается по новой, и так пока не упрется в ограничение и не упадет.

Одним из решений: возвращать строку, которая сейчас передается в конструктор.

```
$scope.customPattern = function(type, size){
    if(size==1){
        var pattern="^\\d+$";
        return pattern;
    }else{
        var pattern="^(\\d+,){" + size-1 + "}\\d+$";
        return pattern;
    }
}
```

Кроме того, второе выражение судя по всему не правильное, так как `,` входит в группу символов, которые должны быть повторены `size-1` раз, а также, `size-1` нужно окружить скобками, в противном случае строка будет формироваться по следующим правилам

```
("^(\\d+,){" + size)-1 + "}\\d+$" => ("(^(\\d+,){size)"-1) + "}\\d+$" 
=> NaN+"}\\d+$" => "NaN}\\d+$"
```

В итоге это должно выглядеть так

```
$scope.customPattern = function(type, size){
    if(size==1){
        var pattern="^\\d+$";
        return pattern;
    }else{
        var pattern="^(\\d+,){" + (size-1) + "}\\d+$";
        return pattern;
    }
}
```